# IVONA add-on for Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

I have set up [IVONA Text-to-Speech](http://ivona.com) (version 1.6.3). There is an integration section in the settings of the reader and there I can integrate it with Firefox, but it doesn't work.

So I want to ask do you know any add-on of IVONA which works for Firefox 32?